# Better way to prevent Firefox add-on variables values to wipe out on browser close? Getting error to use "io/text-streams" module

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I want to save user settings for my firefox add-on in a variable which can be accessible any time I want. It should not get vanished on browser clos. Now how can I do it?

I have tried "simple-storage" module of firefox, it works fine until I quit my browser. When I quit my browser, "simple-storage"s wipes out. So I can't use it.

I have also tried "io/text-streams" module but when I try to use this module in "firefox add-on builder"

```
var io = require("io/text-streams");
io.write("write it");
```

I am getting this error:

```
XPI not built

ModuleNotFoundError: unable to satisfy: require(io/text-streams) from /tmp/tmpePRdMr/addon-sdk-1.12/packages/sadaf2605-4/lib/main.js:2: Looked for it in: /tmp/tmpePRdMr/addon-sdk-1.12/packages/sadaf2605-4/lib/io/text-streams.js /tmp/tmpePRdMr/addon-sdk-1.12/lib/io/text-streams.js
```

Most probably, I would need to install some packages, do the user who will be using my add-on, do they also need to install those packages on their browser?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are testing your add-on with `cfx run`. The [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html#Simple%20Storage%20and%20%22cfx%20run%22) explains why `simple-storage` appears broken and how to solve it.

Comment: actually I have made xpi using `cfx xpi`, still it is not working! I have also removed initialization of that variable.

Comment: Could you post some actual code of what you do with `simple-storage`?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your settings in [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) object (HTML5) .Your values wont vanish after the session is closed ......